# Docker - How can I initiate mysql database with a .sql file running on a container?

Tags: mysql, docker

It is my first time working with docker. I want to create a remote container with test environment for my java application. I also need mysql database. Everything should run on one container (it's a requirement, not my idea).

I need to have a db initiated with .sql file (let's say file.sql located in the same directory as Dockerfile)

Thank you very much for help :)

Here is part of my Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

#Install JRE
RUN     apt-get update && apt-get install default-jre -y

#Install JDK

RUN     apt-get update && apt-get install default-jdk -y

#Install Maven

RUN     apt-get update && apt-get install maven -y

#Install wget
RUN     apt-get update && apt-get install wget -y
#\&& rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*


#Install unzip

RUN     apt-get update && apt-get install unzip -y

#Install glassfish

RUN     mkdir -p /opt && cd opt/
RUN     wget http://download.java.net/glassfish/4.1.1/release/glassfish-4.1.1.zip
RUN     unzip glassfish-4.1.1.zip

#Install mysql

ENV     MYSQL_USER=mysql\ MYSQL_DATA_DIR=/var/lib/mysql \ MYSQL_RUN_DIR=/run/mysqld \ MYSQL_LOG_DIR=/var/log/mysql

RUN     apt-get update && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y mysql-server \&& rm -rf ${MYSQL_DATA_DIR} \&& rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

Comment: Not relevant to the question, but you only need to run `apt-get update` once in this case. You'll shave off some build time by doing so.

Comment: Your requirement to have it in one container is really counter the idea of docker. You can easily use the pre-built mysql container and use its default setup.

Answer (score -1):

First use a ADD to copy your .sql file in the image. Then add a RUN command to restore your DB using mysql commands.

Comment: Wow! That was super fast thank you :) The problem is I do not know how to pass all the configuration params (which are asked for during installation after e.g. apt-get install mysql-server like root password, etc.) via command line

Comment: Try [environment variables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/environment-variables.html).

Comment: Does this work? mysql isn't running during the build itself, so any attempt to connect to the database and run a script will fail

Comment: If the mysql-server install is interactive, you won't be able to use it in the Dockerfile. You really can't use a dedicated container for your DB?

You can copy/paste the way Mysql do it in their Dockerfile, but it is not a good solution: https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/blob/883703dfb30d9c197e0059a669c4bb64d55f6e0d/5.7/Dockerfile

Answer (score -1):

Thank you all for answers!

I found a sollution if anyone will encouter the same problem it's here:

```
RUN     echo "mysql-server mysql-server/root_password password password" | debconf-set-selections
RUN     echo "mysql-server mysql-server/root_password_again password password" | debconf-set-selections
RUN     apt-get update && apt-get -y install mysql-server && service mysql start
```

if mysql is still not starting check /etc/docker/daemon.json, make sure it looks like this:

`{
    "storage-driver":"overlay2"
}`

if you don't have this file execute:

`mkdir -p /etc/docker`

`echo '{"storage-driver":"overlay2"}' > /etc/docker/daemon.json`

`systemctl restart docker.service`